# Assert frees memory in C++

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, assert

Suppose we have a program where we allocate some memory and then we have an **assert** statement some lines after. If the **assert** statement throws and error, what happens with the allocated memory? Does it get free before stopping the program?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[**`assert`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assert.h) on failure, writes the error to **stderr** and calls **[abort()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/abort/)**. which unlike **exit()** doesn't execute the functions registered with **[atexit()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atexit/)**, nor does it call destructors.

Hence, none of your destructors, clean-up code etc  can be called. So it is up to the OS, as the memory isn't freed by the program, before its "*unexpected*" termination.

---

This is probably **by design**, as calling destructors might result in some further error. It terminates at that failed assert, executing no further code.

Comment: It's clearly by design, and it is why you should generally use `assert`, rather than throw an exception, when you detect an error in the code.

Answer (score 4):

The memory stays allocated as the `assert` failure brings down your program.

As part of destroying the process, any modern desktop OS will reclaim the memory. Some embedded operating systems might not be able to do this, although I don't have the name of one on hand.

You can detect memory that has to be reclaimed by the OS this way by using a utility such as Valgrind.